# insert by loop in sql

Tags: insert, csv

I am very new to SQL SCRIPT and I am trying to insert elements in a loop.I initially created a table "student" with  two columns "id","name".

Now I have a CSV file of

```
1,"Sam"
2,"Ranger"
3,"Hardy"
4,"Micheal"
```

I want to insert these elements in a loop rather than using

```
insert into "student"(id,name) values(1,"Sam")
```

likewise for each entry.

I do not how to read the values from the CSV and insert it in a loop like

```
declare @id int 
select @id = 1
while @id >=1 and @id <= 4
begin
insert into student values(@id,@name)
select @id = @id + 1
end
```

Could anyone help me?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: why do you want to insert using a loop instead of, for instance, `bulk insert` option ?

Comment: RBAR! you don't wanna do what you think you have to do

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Sql Server (and noticing that your data has double quotes), have a look at this post - [Importing CSV with optional double quote text qualifier](http://www.jadito.us/2013/08/21/importing-csv-with-optional-double-quote-text-qualifier/).

It discusses two options for importing data using a FORMAT file.

[OPENROWSET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) and [BULK INSERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)